# simple combination

Tags: combinatorics

How much words in length 9 can be write by the letters: A,B,C,D,E When:

1. The letter A appears exactly three times?
2. We will use no more than two different letters? (Simple: AAABBABBA)
3. No letter will not appear next to each other? (Simple: C**DD**EABDCE illegal)
4. The word is also read the same thing backwards? (Simple: CEDDADDEC - CEDDA - ADDEC)
5. Each letter not appear more than twice in word ? (Simple: **AAA**CDEDEB illegal)

tnx .

Comment: Are they "bonus" problems? Anyway, similar problems have been answered in this site. 1,2 and 5 can be solved using exponential generating functions and 4 using a recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

My humble try:

1. Letter A appears exactly three times = ${9\choose3}.4^6$ - A will fill three places in ${9\choose3}$ ways and the rest 6 places could be filled with other four letters with repitition.
2. Will use no more than two letters: ${5\choose2}.2^9$  Any two letters could be chosen in ${5\choose2}$ ways and these two letters could fill 9 places with repitition.
3. No letter will appear next to each other: The first letter could be chosen in 5 ways and the remainder of the digits could be chosen in 4 ways and the process repeats itself eight times.  So a total of $5*(4^8)$.
4. This is tricky.  the middle digit(5) could be chosen in 5 ways. Every digit to the left of it could be chosen in 5 ways and every digit to the right could only be chosen in 1 way for a total of $5^5$ ways.
5. Each letter don't appear more than twice in the word.  This is tricky too. The combinations in which this could happen are (2,2,2,2,1). Thus  the first letter could appear twice in ${9\choose2}$ ways, the second letter could appear in ${7\choose2}$ ways, the third letter could appear in ${5\choose2}$, the fourth letter could appear in ${3\choose2}$ ways and the last one in one way.  So the first combination results in ${9\choose2}\cdot{7\choose2}\cdot{5\choose2}\cdot{3\choose2}$. You will get the answer.

Comment: Congratulations. You just solved another person's homework. To cash in your... oh, wait. Why did you solve another person's homework?

Comment: I slowly getting to understand that student's help is getting a bit little controversial in this site.  This problem I thought was difficult for a student and I thought I could chip in with as much explanation as possible instead of hints.